# How to drag a scene with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the following html page I create a scene with some points, in which you can zoom comfortably by using the mouse wheel.

But what I want to do is to drag that scene after I have zoomed in. I want to press the left mouse button, keep it pressed and then move the mouse. I want the scene to move accordingly (e.g. by changing the x/y coordinates of the camera).

I tried to create a listener to listen to clicks, but when I click somewhere I do not see any console output.

I also searched and found the suggestion to use `DragControls`, but this does not seem to be defined in THREE. At least I get an error when I uncomment these lines.

So how to implement something so I can drag the whole scene (or the camera)?

Code:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(camera);
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                clearAlpha: 1
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(0x228B22, 1);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
            
            // Define a standard Circle
            circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 20);
            
            var max = 50;
            var min = -50;              
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {         
                var object = new THREE.Mesh( circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color('yellow'), opacity: 0.5 } ) );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
                object.position.z = 0;                  
                scene.add( object );            
            }
            
            document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );
            function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
                var fovMAX = 100;
                var fovMIN = 1;
                camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
                camera.fov = Math.max( Math.min( camera.fov, fovMAX ), fovMIN );
                camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makePerspective(camera.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, camera.near, camera.far);
            }
            
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseclick', onDocumentMouseClick, false );
            function onDocumentMouseClick( event ) {
                console.log("mouseclick! " + event.offsetX + "-" + event.offsetY, );
            }
            
            animate();
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            
            //// undefined: 
            //var controls = new THREE.DragControls( objects, camera, renderer.domElement );            
            //controls.addEventListener( 'dragstart', function ( event ) {
            //  event.object.material.emissive.set( 0xaaaaaa );
            //} );
            //
            //controls.addEventListener( 'dragend', function ( event ) {
            //  event.object.material.emissive.set( 0x000000 );
            //} );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using a revision of three.js that is 4 years old. Update to the current revision. `OrbitControls` has the features you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I found a way (see below). The trick is to have a flag that tells if the mouse button is pressed, and then you have an algorithm to determine the difference on the previous position, and move the camera accordingly.

```
var mouseDown = false;
var mousePos = [0,0];
var cameraPos = 0;
        
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
function onMouseDown( event ) {
    mouseDown = true;
    mousePos = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
    cameraPos = camera.position;
}
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
function onMouseUp( event ) {
    mouseDown = false;
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
function onMouseMove( event ) {
    if (mouseDown) {
        // scale factor takes into account the current FOV
        scale =  Math.tan(camera.fov/2 * Math.PI / 180)/1.5;
        dx = mousePos[0] - event.offsetX;
        dy = mousePos[1] - event.offsetY;
        x = cameraPos.x + scale*dx;
        y = cameraPos.y - scale*dy;
        camera.position.x = x;
        camera.position.y = y;
        mousePos = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
        cameraPos = camera.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but do you recall how you devised the math for determining the scale? I'm doing something similar in threejs and I'm still not sure what the best way is of determining that.